# How many maps $φ : N ∪ \{0\} → N ∪ \{0\}$ are there, with the property that $φ(ab) = φ(a) + φ(b)$, for all $a, b ∈ N ∪ \{0\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How many maps $φ :\mathbb N ∪ \{0\} \to \mathbb N ∪ \{0\}$ are there, with the property that $φ(ab) = φ(a) + φ(b)$, for all $a, b \in \mathbb N ∪ \{0\}$?

I know $φ(0)=0$ and $φ(1)=0$. Also for any $φ(n)$ is completely determined by its prime factorization i.e if $n = \prod n_i^{k_i}$ then $φ(n) = \sum k_iφ(n_i)$. So, it is at most countably infinite. How to prove there are only finitely many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\phi(0)=\phi(0x)=\phi(0)+\phi(x)\\
\phi(x)=0$$